# 12 Hour Time Format Comparison in JavaScript and C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I've used the following JavaScript code to validate in the front-end:

```js
function ConvertTime() {
  var inputval = "0" + document.getElementById('FromTime').value;
  var inputval2 = "0" + document.getElementById('ToTime').value;

  var tokens = /([10]?\d) : ([0-5]\d) ([ap]m)/i.exec(inputval);
  if (tokens == null) {
    return null;
  }
  if (tokens[3].toLowerCase() === 'pm' && tokens[1] !== '12') {
    tokens[1] = '' + (12 + (+tokens[1]));
  } else if (tokens[3].toLowerCase() === 'am' && tokens[1] === '12') {
    tokens[1] = '00';
  }

  var tokens2 = /([10]?\d) : ([0-5]\d) ([ap]m)/i.exec(inputval2);
  if (tokens2 == null) {
    return null;
  }
  if (tokens2[3].toLowerCase() === 'pm' && tokens2[1] !== '12') {
    tokens2[1] = '' + (12 + (+tokens2[1]));
  } else if (tokens2[3].toLowerCase() === 'am' && tokens2[1] === '12') {
    tokens2[1] = '00';
  }

  var convertedval = tokens[1] + ' : ' + tokens[2];
  var convertedval2 = tokens2[1] + ' : ' + tokens2[2];

  if (convertedval2 <= convertedval) {
    alert("End time must be greater than start time!");
    alert(convertedval + " " + convertedval2)
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label for="FromTime">From</label>
  <input type="text" class="timepicker form-control" id="FromTime" name="FromTime">
</div>

<div>
  <label for="ToTime">To</label>
  <input type="text" class="timepicker form-control" id="ToTime" name="ToTime">
</div>
<br />

<input type="submit" value="Allocate" class="btn btn-primary" id="button" onclick="ConvertTime()" />
```

So the above code actually checks if end time (ToTime) is greater than start time (FromTime) in 24 hour time format. Then again in server-side, I've used the following to check the 24 hour time format with C#:

```
int FromTime = DateTime.Parse(aAllocateRoom.FromTime).Hour;
int ToTime = DateTime.Parse(aAllocateRoom.ToTime).Hour;

if (ToTime > FromTime && FromTime < ToTime)
{
   //Code
}
```

So the inputs are as follows:

```
FromTime - 10:00 AM  
ToTime   - 11:00 AM
```

So it validates when the time input is as follows:

```
// Alerts FromTime is greater than ToTime as in 24 hour format 1:00 PM is 13:00
FromTime - 01:00 PM 
ToTime   - 11:00 AM
```

Now what I want is I expect to give the following inputs:

```
FromTime - 01:00 PM
ToTime   - 11:00 AM
```

Or

```
FromTime - 11:00 AM
ToTime   - 01:00 PM
```

But only to validate in these cases:

```
  i) FromTime - 01:00 PM //Not possible - Same for AM
     ToTime   - 01:00 PM 

 ii) FromTime - 01:00 PM //Not possible
     ToTime   - 12:00 PM 

iii) FromTime - 01:00 AM //Not possible
     ToTime   - 12:00 AM
```

I am wondering if the above validations are possible both in JavaScript and C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR");
        DateTime Fromtimei=DateTime.ParseExact("130000","HHmmss",provider);
        DateTime Totimei=DateTime.ParseExact("130000","HHmmss",provider);

        DateTime Fromtimeii=DateTime.ParseExact("130000","HHmmss",provider);
        DateTime Totimeii=DateTime.ParseExact("120000","HHmmss",provider);

        DateTime Fromtimeiii=DateTime.ParseExact("010000","HHmmss",provider);
        DateTime Totimeiii=DateTime.ParseExact("000000","HHmmss",provider);


        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Compare(Fromtimeiii,Totimeiii));
        if(DateTime.Compare(Fromtimei,Totimei)==0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Fromtimei.ToString()+"\n"+Totimei.ToString() +"\nNot possible - Same for AM\n\n");
        }
        if(DateTime.Compare(Fromtimeii,Totimeii)==1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Fromtimeii.ToString()+"\n"+Totimeii.ToString() +"\nNot possible\n\n");
        }
        if(DateTime.Compare(Fromtimeiii,Totimeiii)==1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Fromtimeiii.ToString()+"\n"+Totimeiii.ToString() +"\nNot possible\n\n");
        }
```

Output:

8/17/2016 1:00:00 PM
8/17/2016 1:00:00 PM
Not possible - Same for AM

8/17/2016 1:00:00 PM
8/17/2016 12:00:00 PM
Not possible

8/17/2016 1:00:00 AM
8/17/2016 12:00:00 AM
Not possible

Comment: OK. I'll definitely try this and let you know. Besides, just merge this post to earlier one.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DateTime FromTime = DateTime.ParseExact(aAllocateRoom.FromTime,
                                    "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime TomTime = DateTime.ParseExact(aAllocateRoom.ToTime,
                                    "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

if (FromTime < ToTimie)
{
   //Code
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if the above code will validate the last three conditions (i, ii, iii) that I posted. Could you assure to do it both in C# and JavaScript?